# How to get file name what will be opened in Maya Callback: kBeforeOpen

Tags: python, callback, filenames, maya

I want to know filename what will be opened before opening.

Maya have the callback: `kBeforeOpen`

But when i try to read file name in callback function - i receive a name of current file but not file that will be opened.

```
def before(*args, **kwargs):
    print('scene_name', cmds.file(q=True, sn=True))

om.MSceneMessage.addCallback(om.MSceneMessage.kBeforeOpen, before)
```

in empty scene i trying to open file: `"C:/tmp/pen_01.mb"`.

log told me that command `file -o "C:/tmp/pen_01.mb"` is started and then started callback

```
>>> file -options "v=0;" -typ "mayaBinary" -o "C:/tmp/pen_01.mb";
>>> ('scene_name', u'')
```

As you can see, function reads current file name (empty).

How in callback function read information about what exactly will be opened?

Answer (score 2):

In OpenMaya you can do:

```
OpenMaya.MFileIO.beforeOpenFilename()
```

Comment: This is strange that I can't find such class or function in Maya Python API 2.0 (maya.api.OpenMaya). But using Python API 1.0 it works fine. Thank you.